# Android Appstore rejected Smartface

Tags: smartface.io

I am trying to publish app to google play appstrore and rejected. It seems that Google made some security update, because previous version of apps were published? Is there any solution for this?
Note: i have updated latest SDK from manager

> Your APK has been rejected for containing security vulnerabilities, which violates the Malicious Behavior policy. If you submitted an update, the previous version of your app is still live on Google Play.
>
> To properly handle SSL certificate validation, change your code in the checkServerTrusted method of your custom X509TrustManager interface to raise either CertificateException or IllegalArgumentException whenever the certificate presented by the server does not meet your expectations. To confirm you’ve updated correctly, submit the updated version to the Developer Console and check back after five hours. If the app hasn’t been correctly upgraded, we will display a warning

Comment: where is TrustManager code? @Antimony

Comment: @Antimony This is Smartface cross platform sdk android output and no code related with TrustManager

Comment: If you're sure the problem is Smartface, why not report it to them and ask them to fix it?

Comment: :) They don't give support for individual or community licenses. Only way to report here @Antimony

Answer (score 0):

Problem is  using OpenSSL 1.0.1l in the official 4.5 release SMF and next releasing an upgrade to the 4.5 players to OpenSSL 1.0.2g which is the latest release. Wait SMF 4.5.3.

Comment: they have stooped the support for Smartface desktop and also they won't provide any update for Smartface desktop IDE. I think so because i talked to the contact of Smartface and they said.

Comment: what is their plan?

Comment: I don't know exactly but I just got a mail from them that they will be providing 4.5.3 soon they are developing it. Let's hope all goes well.